# How to test more than one assertion as compatible as possible?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

Sometimes it makes sense to have more than one assertion in a unit test method, e.g.

```
@Test
public void testMapReduceProcessing() {
    Tuple tuple = new MetadataTuple();
    Processor instance = new Processor();
    instance.process(tuple);
    assertEquals(State.PROCESSED, tuple.getState());
    assertEquals(1, tuple.getProcessCount());
}
```

PMD and possibly other static analysis tools which I might introduce in the future and want to consider during programming now would raise a `JUnitTestContainsTooManyAsserts` warning because more than one `assert[...]` is present. I could:

- split the methods, but that seems overkill and the recommendation to have only one assert per unit test method doesn't apply here because there's no advantage in splitting here.
- `assertTrue(a.equals(b) && c.equals(d))` which would complicate the assert failure message and also be bad style because `equals` should use `assertEquals`.
- accept that there's no other solution and suppress the PMD check.

I'm not happy with all of them. Is there any elegant approach? I'm looking for JUnit 5 approaches and don't mind extra dependencies.

Comment: From what you're describing, you _want_ to put two asserts in one method and you're trying to find a way to avoid the warning. If you don't agree with the warning, suppress it or turn it off. If you _do_ agree with it, maybe you should split the methods rather than trying to find a dodge around it.

Comment: Such warnings are just wrong. It's perfectly normal, correct, and even desirable to have multiple assertions in a test. One test should test *one thing*, of course, but that doesn't mean *one assertion*.